# Jenkins JNLP slave with ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Is there a way to integrate JNLP slave endpoint with ELB?

Whenever I use ELB endpoint with listener port 50000 to EC2 instance 50000 I get:

```
INFO: Connecting to app.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com:50000
Aug 11, 2017 9:05:54 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP-connect
Aug 11, 2017 9:05:54 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Protocol JNLP-connect encountered an unexpected exception
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Server didn't accept the handshake: HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:385)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:287)
Caused by: org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ConnectionRefusalException: Server didn't accept the handshake: HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpProtocol1Handler.sendHandshake(JnlpProtocol1Handler.java:121)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.LegacyJnlpProtocolHandler$2.call(LegacyJnlpProtocolHandler.java:162)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.LegacyJnlpProtocolHandler$2.call(LegacyJnlpProtocolHandler.java:158)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Aug 11, 2017 9:05:54 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection: None of the protocols were accepted
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:484)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:448)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:287)
```

However when I change the JNLP endpoint url to EC2 instance directly it works fine without any errors.

It seems though ELB is doing some translations that isn't accepted by Jenkins master.

Has anyone have got JNLP connection working from Jenkins slave to master via ELB?

Thanks,

Comment: It sounds like your ELB listener is in HTTP mode and needs to be in TCP mode.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot u are right. Please add in as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish all services via same load balancer (so you can use just 1 domain name) you can use the Classic Load Balancer. With that you can create 2 listeners --> Example 1 https (with ACM ssl certificate) that proxy/offload traffic to Jenkins port HTTP:8080 and other tcp:50000 that forward/bridge traffic to backend servers port 50000.

Comment: Great answer! This helped solve an issue I was having in a completely different context in AWS!

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do but without success :( I can correctly see jenkins on https, but agents can't connect. That make me think I've correctly configured the https listener. Could you please provide a detailed step by step list for dummies of operations to create the agents listener? I've really tried all the combinations coming to my mind, but it's clear I'm still missing something. Thank you

Comment: @DanieleRicci did you find the solution? Like you, I found this answer not clear.

Comment: Hi @andolsizied , yes, I was able to solve the problem, but I do not remember which was the key :( sorry . I remember the answer is very close to the solution I was just missing a single details. I checked my ELB in order to try to remember, but I wasn't able to, so sorry :(

Comment: Hi @DanieleRicci, I finally found the solution, in fact I use ingress-nginx controller which does not support TCP or UDP services. For this reason this Ingress controller uses the flags --tcp-services-configmap and --udp-services-configmap to point to an existing config map where the key is the external port. (More details here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/ and implementation https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-setup-guide/configure-ports-jnlp-agents#values-yaml-configure-jnlp)